# Given a real number, how do I produce an elliptic curve with j-invariant equal to that number?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have formula for computing the j-invariant but I was wondering if given number $j$, is there a formula for getting a curve  $y^2=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$ with j-invariant j?

Answer (score 5):

I found it!

\begin{eqnarray*}
Y^2 + XY = X^3 -\dfrac{36}{j-1728}X-\dfrac{1}{j-1728}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This construction works unless $j=0$ or $j=1728$. But $y^2+y=x^3$ has $j=0$, and $y^2=x^3+x$ has $j=1728$.